# Apex add list elements inside json without ()

Tags: apex, json, list

```
    List<List<String>> listaCot = new List<List<String>>();
    detalleCot = '{"Cdocu":"31","Ndocu":"","Codi":"'+variable+'"}';
    listaCot.add(new List<String>{detalleCot});
    jsonString = '{"Fecha":"'+fecha+'","Detalle":['+listaCot+']}';

//jsonString Shows = {"Fecha":"'+fecha+'","Detalle":[({"Cdocu":"131","Ndocu":"","Codi":"0301-011626"}), ({"Cdocu":"31","Ndocu":"","Codi":"0301-011627"})]}
```

The problem is that is adding () inside the json as you can see in the comments.
Im trying to iterate and use join to remove the () but i cant put each element inside the jsonString variable.

```
        for (integer n = 0; n<listaCot.size(); n++){

            system.debug(string.join(listaCot[n],','));
//This shows each element without the ().
        }
```

Is there a way to just remove the () or to put all the elements in another string ?

Answer (score 1):

If you decided to use a plain string concatenation, you would need to use JSON.serialize:

```
jsonString = '{"Fecha":"'+fecha+'","Detalle":'+JSON.serialize(listaCot)+'}';
```

Note that you shouldn't be using these sorts of methods anyways; it's far more productive to use proper Objects and serialize them:

```
jsonString = JSON.serialize(new Map<String, Object> {
  'Fecha' => fecha,
  'Detalle' => listaCot
});
```

Comment: When doing the first option you said it shows this: ["{\"Cdocu\":\"31\",\"Ndocu\":\"\",\"Item\":2,\"Codi\":\"0301-011626\"] and the second shows something similar.

Comment: @Oscar Yes, you should make the entire thing a set of nested maps/lists. Do not write plain JSON strings in your code. That's asking for trouble.